# PHP SOAP service returns Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s

Tags: php, xml, web-services, soap

I'm trying upload orders to a remote server with soap but when I send the XML what the SOAP expects I got this error:

```
Exception: System.ArgumentNullException
Message: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
Stack trace: at System.IO.StringReader..ctor(String s)
at System.Xml.XmlDocument.LoadXml(String xml)
```

I'm calling the service like this:

```
<?php
 $doc = new DomDoument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
 $doc->formatOutput = true;
  /* lots of code here */
 $xml = saveXML();
$client = new SoapClient('http://mx.biopont.com/services/Vision.asmx?wsdl',array("trace" => 1, 'features' => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS));
//$result = $client->RendelesFeladas(array('rendelesxml' => $xml));
try {
    $result = $client->__soapCall('RendelesFeladas', array("rendelesxml"=>$xml));
    }catch (SoapFault $e) {
      echo "SOAP Fault: ".$e->getMessage()."<br />\n";
    }
?>
```

the XML which is generated by DOMDocument is look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rendeles verzio="1.0">
  <fej>
    <partnerid>4476</partnerid>
    <idegen_megrendelesszam>d836033</idegen_megrendelesszam>
    <szallitasi_mod>51</szallitasi_mod>
    <szallitasi_megj>gfhgfhgfhfhh</szallitasi_megj>
  </fej>
  <tetelek>
    <tetel>
      <tetelszam>1</tetelszam>
      <cikkszam>102050009</cikkszam>
      <mennyiseg>1</mennyiseg>
    </tetel>
  </tetelek>
</rendeles>
```

I don't have a clue what did i wrong. Because I construct the XML according to an example file which I got from the developer of the web-service. And actualy at the very first time I ran the call everything went fine since than I get error, and I didn't made changes to the xml, there were no changes in the SOAP service. So I don't get it.

Can somebody help me, point out what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found it.

For the partner who runs under the ID 4476 I added a fake ZIP code and the soap service couldn't figure out what to do whit it so the user 4476 was corrupted. After I updated the address information the order was accepted by the soap service.